# What is difference between BindingIdentifier and IdentifierReference

Tags: ecmascript-6

Let's look at http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-expressions

As you can see:

```
IdentifierReference[Yield, Await]:
    Identifier
    [~Yield]yield
    [~Await]await

BindingIdentifier[Yield, Await]:
    Identifier
    [~Yield]yield
    [~Await]await

Identifier:
    IdentifierName but not ReservedWord
```

Both `Identifiers (Binding and Reference)` contains the same thing. What's the point of this? What are they different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that they occur in different contexts and have different algorithms related to them.

- An `IdentifierReference` is a variable name that is used in an expression, getting evaluated with [ResolveBinding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-resolvebinding) to a reference
- A `BindingIdentifier` is a variable name that is used to create a binding - in variable and function declarations, in parameters, in destructuring, in `catch` clauses, in `for` clauses, etc.

In their [EarlyErrors](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-identifiers-static-semantics-early-errors), an `IdentifierReference` may refer to `eval` or `argument`, but a `BindingIdentifier` creating a binding for them is a syntax error (in strict mode). The only algorithm that they share is [StringValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-identifiers-static-semantics-stringvalue). An `IdentifierReference` has a [IsValidSimpleAssignmentTarget](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-identifiers-static-semantics-isvalidsimpleassignmenttarget) check and an [Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-identifiers-runtime-semantics-evaluation), while a `BindingIdentifier` has [BoundNames](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-identifiers-static-semantics-boundnames) and a [BindingInitialisation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-identifiers-runtime-semantics-bindinginitialization) procedure.